# Font get dark on mozilla and IE

Tags: html, css

i am using 'Franklin Gothic' font for website and font looks good on chrome and safari but on internet explorer and mozilla firefox it looks darker. can anyone help me to sort out this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skHcZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi can you define the font `color`and `font-weight` as below sample

```
class{color:#000!important;font-weight:normal!important;}
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set the color on your own:

```
* {
   color: black // whatever you want
}
```

Comment: hello
Thanks for reply color of my body text is blue, when i open my website in chrome it shows me perfect, but in ie its font weight is get high and i am not using anywhere font weight css property

Comment: Can you update your question with an image? Is Franklin Gothic a Google's font?

Comment: sure just a moment

Comment: did you got the problem

Comment: Why don't you set the `font-weight` property on your own?